# Centering content horizontally using flexbox

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I'm struggling to center horizontally some content in my container:

https://jsfiddle.net/y56t31q9/6/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Not centering content horizontally? */
}
.item {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <section class="item"></section>
  <section class="item"></section>
  <footer class="item"></footer>
</div>
```

I would have thought *justify-content* would have done the trick, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The property `justify-content:center` aligns the flex-items along the flex direction - use `align-items:center`- see demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;/*NEW*/
}
.item {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 250px;/*NEW*/
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <section class="item"></section>
  <section class="item"></section>
  <footer class="item"></footer>
</div>
```

Refer: [Flexbox W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

Below is an image that applies when `flex-direction` is *row*:

[image]

a. Main axis alignment : justify-content

b. Cross axis alignment : align-items

When the `flex-direction` is *row*, the main-axis is horizontal but when it is *column*, it is the other way around.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth response! Means a lot, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add  `align-items:center;`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `flex-direction:column` and `max-width:500px`.
Give some fixed width say 100px and it will work properly. If you are using `flex-direction:column` use `align-items:center` property to horizontally center and `justify-center` if it is `row`.